# Are conflicting transitive dependencies a serious issue in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, clojure, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a project X which shows quite a lot of conflicting dependencies in the dependency hierarchy (as displayed in Eclipse's dependency hierarchy view). I see lots of things like:

```
clojure: 1.3.0 (omitted for conflict with 1.4.0) [compile]
```

This usually occurs because two of the libraries used by X specify two different versions of some other library - i.e. the conflicts are occuring because of shared transitive dependencies. In quite a few cases the conflicts are in 3rd party libraries I can't directly control.

Fortunately everything builds and runs fine right now, but I'm worried if this situation might cause problems in the future.

Is this a problem I should be worried about and if so, what should I be doing about it?

Comment: Ever since my "xml and xml parser adventure" I try to mitigate these problems, ie. at least TRY. A library depending on one and only one version of another which then is omitted because another library needs a newer version of the same library feels like a well executed kick in the balls. I usually try to manage the versions of conflicting 3rd party libraries..although I have to admit it does not always work. Or work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such conflicts can be serious.

You don't know if there is an incompatible change in a dependency when comparing versions one with another (There shouldn't be when comparing minor versions, but who knows exactly?). Or maybe some dependency depends on a buggy behavior of another dependency. What if this bug has been fixed? That one module depending on the bug will fail to execute properly.

You should exclude conflicting dependencies (more likely excluding lower versions). For each exclusion you enter, you have to check, if there are incompatible changes between the excluded version and the version that is now in use. If that is the case you have to check dependencies that depend on that module, if they are  affected by such changes.

Answer (score 3):

Most times this should be ok, if the newer version has been selected by maven.

You should start to worry if conflicts occur with differences in the major version (the first number) or if the newer version has been omitted. Unitstests help a lot to catch these problems, but often the eclipse project and the maven dependencies differ in subtle ways (debug-scope, etc). The only real protection seem to be integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

It *can* be a serious issue as you never can be sure exactly what happens, and this is bad. I think big point of using maven configuration is being explicit about what happens and what are the dependencies used.

As to what you should do about it, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12995780/365237) - you should push towards to fixing 'em by explicitly configuring which version to use and which to leave out, and [maven-enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/) can make it a lot easier with [DependencyConvergence rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html). That's there to protect you from conflicting transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a problem. Usually different versions contain the same classes. In the end java loads only one version of that class. It may be the old or the new version. It may cause runtime errors like mysterious NoSuchMethodError, ClassNotFoundExceptions etc.